# How to calculate the phase spectrum

Tags: complex, fourier-analysis

I have the following frequency characteristics in the Fourier domain:

$$H(\omega)=\frac{-\omega^2}{63170s^{-2}-\omega^2+355.1s^{-1}i\omega}$$

How do I find the phase spectrum from this? I should plot both the negative and positive frequencies.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please add to your question the code you have developed so far, displayed in Mathematica format.

Comment: Have you looked at the command `FourierTransform`? Or maybe (because you have the symbol `s`), you want the `LaplaceTransform`? `Plot` is useful for showing your results.

Comment: Could you clarify what the terms are. What is `s` there? `s` is normally used for Laplace transform variable. But you say the above is Fourier transform.

Comment: @Nasser - I would (and already have) put my money on `s` standing for seconds. The function given is not really a Fourier transform of anything physically meaningful in the time domain, unless of course the force driving the oscillator had the form of a Dirac delta function w.r.t. time, then it's the Fourier transform of the acceleration of the oscillator vs. time.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP so you are saying the above is $\frac{-\omega^2}{63170-\omega^2+355.1  (I \omega)}$ ?  This is very confusing. One does not put the units in the equation itself as is. How would one know for example than `M` stands for `kg` unit or for some variable? But if this is the case, the I'd use the fact that  $s=I \omega$ and get the Laplace transform function, then make one call to `BodePlot`

Comment: @Nasser yes, this is exactly what I'm saying. He is stating that the squared eigenfrequency of the oscillator in question is 63170 squared radians per second squared, the damping is 355.1 inverse seconds. Of course I could be completely wrong, but this looks so much like the second moment of a classical oscillator... But I see no need to do any transformations, because this is a response function. We can either get the phase response from it (vs. frequency) or we need to know the driving force to get the response vs. time.

Comment: Some googling shows, that this is most likely not so much an oscillator, but rather two RC high pass filters in series. In which case bbgodfrey's answer is more accurate than mine.

Comment: @Nasser  The rescaling `ω -> ω/s` eliminates `s` from the expression, and with it any need to interpret this undefined quantity.  Nonetheless, I, like @LLIAMnYP, believe that `s` is meant to represent seconds.  Certainly, this is dimensionally correct.

Answer (score 2):

Given the [standard definitions](http://pages.jh.edu/~signals/spectra/spectra.html) of amplitude and phase spectra, I believe that `s^-1` should be interpreted as units of inverse seconds.  With this supposition,

```
h = -ω^2/(63170 + 355.1 I ω - ω^2)
```

and the amplitude and phase spectra are `Abs[h]` and `Arg[h]`, respectively, with `ω` measured in inverse seconds.  The curves have the typical shapes,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`H[\omega]` looks a lot like a function for a driven damped oscillator. I'll use `x` instead of `\omega` for brevity. Its not the response function, though, this looks more like the second derivative w.r.t time. So I would define another function, which would be proportional to the complex amplitude response function: `a[x_]:=-H[x]/x^2`. As it's the *complex* amplitude, it already contains information about both phase and amplitude, there's really no need to *look* further for the phase spectrum. The magnitude of it `Abs[a[x]]` will give you the amplitude response, while `Arg[a[x]]` gives the phase response. Here's some code:

```
h[x_]:=-x^2/(63170-x^2+355.1 I x)
a[x_]:=-h[x]*63170/x^2
(* The multiplier 63170 serves to normalize the function
to unity at zero frequency, it hasn't got any other special significance *)
Plot[{Abs[a[x]],Arg[a[x]]},{x,-1000,1000}]
```

It returns

[image: spectra]